# Include Jar inside other providing error

Tags: java, jar

I have two jar files (say jar1 &  jar2). I am using some methods of jar1 from jar2. Now I want to inclue jar1 inside jar2 and use methods of jar2.

When I am calling methods of jar2 it provides following error

> Could not find class 'com.package...classOfJar1', referenced from method com.package....methodOfJar2.

and

> 01-04 07:09:59.290: E/AndroidRuntime(17678): java.lang.VerifyError: com/package/...classOfJar2

But if I palce two jars into my test project independently, it works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include JARs into WARs (web archive).
You can include JARs and WARs into EARs (enterprise application archive).
But you cannot include a JAR into another JAR.